# CSS small circle becomes oval

Tags: javascript, css, geometry

I use small circles as a carousel indicators and I have a very strange issue. The smallest circles become oval, but if I zoom in then it becomes a circle again.

[image]

```js
const circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');
circles.forEach(circle => {
  circle.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    circles.forEach(circle => {
      circle.classList.remove('active')
    })
    circle.classList.add('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 100px;
}

.circle {
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%; 
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.circle:first-child, .circle:last-child{
  width: 4px;
  height: 4px;
}

.circle:nth-child(2), .circle:nth-child(4){
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
}

.circle:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

.circle.active {
  width: 36px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #131417;
  height: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="circle"></div> 
    <div class="circle"></div> 
    <div class="circle"></div> 
    <div class="circle"></div> 
    <div class="circle"></div> 
</div>
```

Try clicking on the different circles and when you click on the second to last item you will notice that the last one becomes oval. (If you can not replicate this, you must be viewing it in a small screen so try zooming out)

If I try to use bigger sizes for these circles everything seems perfect.

I tried using SVGs instead of the CSS circles, but the result is same. Can anyone guess why this is happening?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Works perfectly for me in the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome, regardless of the window size.

Comment: The only thing I would suggest is to add to ".circle" another property "box-sizing:border-box". Maybe this would help.

Comment: I can’t reproduce the issue on Chrome/Edge Windows 10.

Comment: I use latest chrome as well and my co-workers also car reproduce this. I tried on different PCs and different browsers. try zooming out. @Azu thanks for your suggestion, but that did not help

Comment: There will be edge effects as the browser tries to map between CSS pixels and actual screen pixels. Have you tried Unicode circles instead to see if they expand/contract better?

Comment: Hey man use gap property in flexbox not margins also don't  add padding to flexbox ! Problem solved (  make your icons large too ! )

Comment: @Sanmeet The point is that I don't wont to make them larger :)) gap does not work either

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I tried to enlarge the image. You see that the other images are not circles either... I suppose it comes from the browser rendering.

Comment: So, there is no way to fix this?

Comment: I think it's a very minor problem so you could leave it as it is.

Comment: Once you notice this, it looks very ugly :D

Comment: I'd suggest you to enlarge the circles. The smallest one is only 4px x 4px. It's very hard to click on. This is just from users point of view:)

Comment: Actually those are not clickable in reality. There are arrows which are for that purpose. these buttons are just indicators. Thanks for your suggestions anyways

Comment: I don't think that this is browser rendering issue, because if you try to render the circle separately, it looks perfect